# Put div above div with bottom vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

This is my sample html code:

```css
.questions-table-main {
        border-right: 3px solid rgb(242,244,247);
        width:189px;
        float:left;
        padding-right:30px;
        padding-top:10px;
        display:table;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .questions-table-main-category {
        /* padding-top: 20px; */
        text-align : center;
    }
    .questions-table-main-firm {
        height:85px;
        background-color:rgb(242,244,247);
        text-align: center;
        display: table-row;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

```html
<div class="questions-table-main">
       <div class="questions-table-main-category">
          <img src="img/communication.png" alt="communication"/>
       </div>
       <div class="questions-table-main-firm">
          <div class="questions-table-main-firm-image">
             <span class="questions-table-firm-helper">
             <img src="img/allianz.png" alt="allianz" /></span>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Let me clear this mess. I need to put `<div class="questions-table-main-firm">` on the bottom of `<div class="questions-table-main">`. Next thing I need to do is that `<div class="questions-table-main-category">` must be above `<div class="questions-table-main-firm">` with 27px space between them. I was trying to do that with `padding-top`, but it's impossible because i have some different images with different dimensions. Now `<div class="questions-table-main-category">` is on the top of parrent div. How to fix that ?

Comment: what happens when you give `margin-bottom:27px;` to your `.questions-table-main-category` element???

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what is wrong, or what is it that you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Maybe my edit made this easier to understand ?

Comment: see my answer @abecadlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `position: absolute;` and `top`. For bottom div use `top: 0` so that it says at top and for first div use `top: 112px` including height(85) and margin 27.

```css
.questions-table-main {
  border-right: 3px solid rgb(242,244,247);
  width:189px;
  padding-right:30px;
  padding-top:10px;
  display:block;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
 
}
.questions-table-main-category {
  text-align : center;
  height:85px;
  top: 112px; /* height 85 + 27 margin*/
  position: absolute;
}
.questions-table-main-firm {
  height:85px;
  background-color:rgb(242,244,247);
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
   <div class="questions-table-main-category">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/189x85" alt="communication"/>
   </div>
   <div class="questions-table-main-firm">
      <div class="questions-table-main-firm-image">
   
         <span class="questions-table-firm-helper">
         <img src="https://placehold.it/189x85" alt="allianz" /></span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the display table atributes, do it as follows:

```css
.questions-table-main {
    width:189px;
    float:left;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding-top:10px;
    height: 200px;
}
.questions-table-main-category {
    /* padding-top: 20px; */
    text-align : center;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.questions-table-main-firm {
    background-color:rgb(242,244,247);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions-table-main">
   <div class="questions-table-main-category">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="communication"/>
   </div>
   <div class="questions-table-main-firm">
      <div class="questions-table-main-firm-image">
         <span class="questions-table-firm-helper">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="allianz" /></span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but <div class="questions-table-main-firm"> must be on the bottom of parrent div.